# Как правильно составить такое условие в PHP?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Привет всем. Нужна Ваша помощь - мне нужно написать условие: если URL содержит в себе /administrator/ тогда условие выполняется. URL может быть вида site.ru/administrator/, а может быть site.ru/administrator/index.php?option=com_k2&view=media и любого другого вида. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярное выражение или решить задачу другим способом. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` и `strpos()` вам в помощь

Comment: .

   if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'administrator') !== false) {
      // логика
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/administrator/') !== false){ 
   //выполнение условия
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему `if(preg_match("/administrator/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))`